# EXCEL VBA: Class Sub without parameter

Tags: excel, vba, class

I have a probably quite simple question. Nonetheless I was not able to find the answer on the net: How do I declare and or use a sub for a class that just serves to do some computations on the object's properties but that does not need any further parameters to do so?

As an example I am aiming to do something like this:

Class Group_of_Groups:

```
Private SizeGroup1 As Integer
Private SizeGroup2 As Integer
Private TotalNumberOfPeople As Integer
....
Public Sub CountPeople()
   TotalNumberOfPeople = SizeGroup1 + SizeGroup2
End Sub
```

In the main sub:

```
...
Dim GoG As New Group_of_Groups
GoG.SizeGroup1 = 5
GoG.SizeGroup2 = 10
GoG.CountPeople()
MsgBox GoG.TotalNumberOfPeople
...
```

Of cause I want the messagebox to display 15.

However, it seems I am not alowed to have this standalone command "GoG.CountPeople()" - when compiling excel gives the error that a "=" is missing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you make a function that has sizegroup1 and 2 as parameters and returns the summation instead..? This is **MUCH** clearer and doesn't require a "public.... sub" nor does it require you to dim private variables before.. Usually though, if you have a sub that doesn't actually return any variable, you can just call it with its name (not with `GoG.`)

Comment: @Sifu: Given the class variables are declared `Private` in the posted code, there must be accessors to `Get/Set` them. But yes, in principle, this might help clarify the code. This is a very cut-down example, so maybe it's just meant as such without unnecessary complications.

Comment: I see! Sorry then for my minsunderstanding and good luck!

Comment: You might consider making TotalNumberOfPeople a public property get (with no let) that does the calculation. The only reason to have a CountPeople sub is that it's so calculation intensive that you want your class to have the equivalent of manual calculation. If that's the case, you should have setters that set the private variables and getters that do the math and return a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you should call it as follows:

```
GoG.CountPeople
```

i.e. without the parentheses, otherwise the code thinks you're returning a value from a function, therefore it expects to see an `=` where the value will be assigned to a variable.

Also, I had to make the class variable `Public` to compile for me, but I'm sure you must have your own accessors.

Comment: careful though in `.NET`, calling a sub requires the `()`. `SubName()`. Or Visual Studio just places them for you..

Comment: @Sifu: You are correct, but the tags in the question indicate VBA, so no .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reluctant to write a function with parameters?

```
Function CountPeople(SizeGroup1, SizeGroup2)
   CountPeople = SizeGroup1 + SizeGroup2
End Function

Sub mySub()    
   g1 = 5
   g2 = 10
   MsgBox CountPeople(g1, g2)
End Sub
```